# Cant update Timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am having problem with my MySQL database.
I have 4 column id, user, msg, time.
Type of time is "timestamp",
Attributes is " ON UPDATE current_time_stamp"

but it always storing **0000-00-00 00:00**.
I want to store it current date and time please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Comment: Date and datetime values need to be in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), that is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. Anything else gets trashed, mangled, or turned into all zeroes.

Comment: Use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

I really am not able to understand what is wrong in it. As an alternative, you try to get the current time using date() function of php and store it in your database table.

```
$dt=date('h:i:s:a')
```

Will give you the current time in hour:minute:second:am/pm format.
To get date also, you can use:

```
$dt=date('y-m-d h:i:s:a')
```

Hope it will help you.